# TensorFlow Setup Issue

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just setup TensorFlow on my MacBook Pro (El Capitan) and ran the installation test suggested on the website. This is what shows up:

```
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

> **b'Hello, TensorFlow!'**

Are the "b" and quotations around Hello, TensorFlow a result of something wrong done during installation?

Thanks!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal

Comment: Thank you for your help!